# How to make the loading spinner implemented on a button stop after the script finish running?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a submit button that runs a script when clicking on it.

```html
<input type="submit" value="Download Files" class="btn btn-success col-md-4"  id="load" data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin'></i> Downloading Files">
```

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.button('loading');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $this.button('reset');
  }, 8000);
});
```

The script running time is not constant; it varies from time to time. I want the loading to start on clicking on the submit button and end after the script finishes running. How can I do that?

Comment: What is "the script"?

Comment: You just need to call `button('reset')` when the script stops running... I'm not sure what answer you're expecting here given the information you've given us

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I want to know what function to use to stop the loading , I don't know the time so I would depend on a function runs when the script finish

Comment: It depends on what the script is doing, so we need to see that code. Assuming it's an AJAX call, use one of the many callbacks available.

Comment: It's a php script that downloads some files , I don't know AJAX , So please if you know a function that could achieve what I want write it

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {    
var $this = $(this);
$this.button('loading');
setTimeout(function() {
$this.button('reset');
}, 8000);
});
```

Need some add on. Add these external java script in the following order

- [jQuery.min.js](//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js)
- [bootstrap.min.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js)

[Here is the working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ankurgarg36/2xes9ad0/)